# Wordpress Admin logs me out immediately after successful login

Tags: wordpress, logout

I have uploaded a Wordpress site from local system. After a few changes in the database script and wp_config the website is running perfectly. But the problem is that whenever I try to login in the Admin area it seems to login but immediately takes me back to the login page as if it has logged me out. To resolve, I did the following but nothing worked:

- removed browser cache.
- run it on another browser.
- renamed Plugins dir, just to disallow all plugins.
- renamed .htaccess so that it will no more be affecting the website.

Please help!

Babur

Comment: Double check the settings as mentioned here http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-fix-wordpress-keeps-logging-out-problem/

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution may be to make sure your site url is configured correctly. Normally you would do this in the general settings, but since you don't have access you can add this code to the wp-config.php file in the wp-content directory.

```
define('WP_HOME','http://yoursiteurl.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://yoursiteurl.com');
```

If you have not pointed a DNS record to the site yet you will need to use the IP address of the server.

After adding these line try logging in again. Then you can alter the settings normally.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I did change the wp_config for those two lines with no luck. 
Infact before I had checked the corresponding entries (siteurl and home) in wp_options table. They are exactly the same, so may be I don't need to modify wp_config for this.

There's a jiggle. This is only a domain name: qudratullahshahab.com. There's another domain with hosting http://www.softimpetus.com.
A subdomain qudratullahshahab.com.softimpetus.com has been created using  softimpetus.com cpanel, and the website content have been uploaded under this subdomain root.

So http://qudratullahshahab.com is made live temporarily unless we get a hosting for this domain. I guess the routing issue after admin login could be because of this 'unusual' hosting, but not sure.

Babur